# instantiating an object inside an instance method in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

i`m trying to creat a little game using javascript and everything went well until i have to fire something, i nedeed to instantiate a "bullet" and fire it, but when calling "new bullet()" i got an "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ".
How do i instantiate an object inside another object method?

this is what i done

```
function bullet(){
    //here it would be state for the bullet, like x and y and thigs
    console.log("bullet created");
}

function gun(){
    //state for the gun, amount of bullets and sort
    console.log("gun created");

    this.fire = function(){
        //here we instantiate a bullet and fire it
        console.log("begin fire");
        var bullet = new bullet();
        console.log("created bullet to fire");
    }
}

var gun = new gun();

gun.fire();
```

Comment: rename `var gun` and `var bullet` to something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in javascript your variables get hoisted.  To be clear what that means, the compiler treats the code you wrote as if you had written:

```
function gun(){
    //state for the gun, amount of bullets and sort
    console.log("gun created");
    this.fire = function(){
        var bullet;
        //here we instantiate a bullet and fire it
        console.log("begin fire");
        bullet = new bullet();
        console.log("created bullet to fire");
    }
}
```

So in JS all variable declarations get moved to the top of the current function scope.  Note, that this isn't true in all programming languages.  In some languages you could get away with the above and `bullet` the variable would succesfully replace `bullet` the function.

The best solutions is to give your variable a different name.

```
function gun(){
    //state for the gun, amount of bullets and sort
    console.log("gun created");
    this.fire = function(){
        //here we instantiate a bullet and fire it
        console.log("begin fire");
        var mybullet = new bullet();
        console.log("created bullet to fire");
    }
}
```

Also, as brought up by hungarian, I think you are misunderstanding the `new` operator in JS.

Edit: clarified meaning of hoisting.

Comment: error: bullet is not a constructor but if you change the var bullet to bullets, then it works http://jsfiddle.net/f962Y/

Comment: yes, that is also a problem, but it's not the problem he was having.  Besides calling the function with new would just set `this` equal to a new instance of an object with its constructor pointed to the function but it would still "work".  go ahead and try it.  JS doesn't crash and burn when you call a function with new, it just isn;t doing exactly what you might be expecting.

Comment: @Huangism: I think you misunderstood the point of this answer. The code is a demonstration/explanation of the problem, not a solution. The solution is in the final sentence: *"give it a different name."*

Comment: @Obtuse: I don't think that was Huangism's intention. I think he actually run the code and got the error `bullet is not a constructor` (that's the error Firefox shows), under the assumption that the code you posted is the solution.

Comment: I am just saying, if an answer is posted with code, then the code should be working. It's updated now so it's good to go

Comment: @Huangism: *" then the code should be working"* Not every code in an answer is part of the solution. It did what it was supposed to do: demonstrate the problem. If you just copy and paste the code without actually reading the answer, then that's your problem. The solution could have been more clear though.

Comment: @FelixKling.  Interesting.  A better error would be `bullet is not a function`, because that's what is happening.  Is there any function that can't be called like a constructor in JS?  (not that the function would work if it uses `this`)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. So, `bullet is not a constructor` implies that it's not a function. It also tells you, without seeing the code, that you tried to use `new` on a value that isn't a function. The error message is actually more precise.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but you made a mistake, variables get hoisted at function level and you put `var bullet` not inside `this.fire`.

Comment: @Givi  You are right.  Just a mistake I made throwing the answer together to fast.  I'll go back and clean it up.  thanks.

Comment: thakns, all of this would`nt happened if i had stick to naming conventions and named classes Capitalized, but at least i know now that js is a mean creation

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening.

When you call `gun.fire();`, the local variable `bullet`is declared and initialized to 'undefined' while the rest of the expression is evaluated. The evaluation of this expression looks for a variable called `bullet`, and finds it in the local scope, ignoring the bullet variable in the global scope.

This taught me something new about javascript, variable declarations aren't atomical.

To solve the problem, rename the bullet variable in your fire method, to something like firedBullet.